# Selecting specific rows of csv based on a column's value in python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file which I am reading using a DictReader and I want to select rows of the file based on if the values in the Name column match the names I give as a list.

The file looks like:

```
Name Age Gender
Matt 22  M
Jen  21  F
Greg 22  M
```

I've tried something like this but rows returns as empty

```
file = csv.DictReader('file.csv',fieldnames=fieldnames,delimiter='~')

Names = ['Greg', Jen']

for i in Names:
   rows = [row for row in file if row['Name'] == i]
```

I would like the code to produce the following as rows:`{Jen: 21: F, Greg: 22: M}` I'm not sure if this formatting is correct.

Please note that I am intentionally not using a dataframe library such as pandas due to constraints beyond my control.

Comment: You are not loading correctly the file

Answer (score 2):

The way you read the csv file is not correct [csv.DictReader example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). this code should work:

```
Names = ["Greg", "Jen"]    
with open("csvFile.csv", newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    rows = [row for row in reader if row['Name'] in Names]

print(rows)
```

the output is :

```
[{'Gender': 'F', 'Name': 'Jen', 'Age': '21'}, {'Gender': ' M', 'Name': 'Greg', 'Age': '22'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is more efficient to iterate over the rows once instead of iterating over the rows for each name. This is especially true on large files.

```
filtered_rows = []

for row in file:
    if row['Name'] in Names:
        filtered_rows.append(row)
```

Same solution using list comprehension

```
filtered_rows = [
    row
    for row in file
    if row['Name'] in Names 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `"file.csv'` has mistmatched quotes: it should be `"file.csv"` or `'file.csv'`. There's a missing quote in `Names = ['Greg', Jen']`; it should be `Names = ['Greg', 'Jen']`. And the delimiter should be `' '` (a space). You will need to open the file before you call the `Dictreader` method. Finally: the for loop can be simplified.

Example of working code:

```py
import csv

with open('example.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    file = csv.DictReader(csvfile,  delimiter=' ')

    Names = ['Greg', 'Jen']
    print(file)

    rows = [row for row in file if row['Name'] in Names]
```

In the example.csv file:

```
Name Age Gender
Matt 22 M
Jen 21 F
Greg 22 M
```

Answer (score 0):

You used the operator `==` on your loop. Remove the loop and use the operator `in`

```
rows = [row for row in file if row['Name'] in Names]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not opening the file correctly.
Change the delimeter and your code to this:

```
from csv import DictReader

with open('test.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    file = DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=';')

    Names = ['Greg', 'Jen']
    rows = [row for row in file if row['Name'] in Names]
    print(rows)
```

The output I get Is:

```
[{'Gender': 'M', 'Name ': 'Greg ', 'Age ': '22'},{'Gender': 'F', 'Name ': 'Jen  ', 'Age ': '21'}]
```

If you want to learn more about csv with python, check this [link](https://realpython.com/python-csv/)